# Как получить все view, содержащиеся в lavout и затем извлечь из них текст

Tags: java, android, textview

К примеру, 1 lavout может содержать разное (заранее неизвестное) количество textview. Есть ли способ извлечь текст из них и поместить его в переменную?

Comment: перебрать всех детей и проверить на instanceof `TextView`...но эт как то не особо правильно наверно)

Comment: @ermak0ff, а почему не правильно?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну эт скорее из за всем известной байки "о скорости работы `instanceof` и если есть потребность в нем, значит скорее всего неверная архитектура приложения"....но это лишь "байка"))

Comment: @ermak0ff, ну, тогда можно в `try` обернуть)))

Comment: от части эт верно, так как даже если мы генерируем `TextView` динамически, проще хранить ссылки на них, а не перебирать потом весь корневой лейаут

Comment: @ermak0ff, ну вообще да... Текст весь этот хранить изначально где-то и оттуда и отображать. Тогда и вытаскивать ничего не надо будет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нее, а так да, приведенный Вами способ является самым  оптимальным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Пробегитесь циклом по всем детям контейнера.
2. Проверьте является ли ребёнок `TextView`
3. Если да - вытащите текст

   ```
   String text = "";
   for(int i = 0; i<someContainer.getChildCount(); i++)
   {
       if(someContainer.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
       {
           text += ((TextView)someContainer.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: попробовала предложенный Вами вариант, + передала text в  textview2, получается, что в textview2 передается содержимое только последнего textview, из которого извлекали текст. Следовательно, переменная text хранит только 1 текст.

Comment: @ЕленаЧччччччч, всё верно. Я написал ровно то, что вы попросили - для каждого текстового поля в контейнере создаётся объект типа стринг и в него помещается текст из текстового поля. Чтобы получить в одну переменную текст всех полей - надо не новую переменную каждый раз создавать, а дополнять существующую. См. обновлённый код.